# example for setting destination width and height and getting updated camera info when using image_proc/resize

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, could someone please give me a concrete example about how to use the resize() function via command line?

This [link](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/issues/451) seems to be promising, but it doesn't show how to set destination width and height and how to get updated camera info.

This [link](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/issues/297) is also similar, but I don't understand which .h file it's about and why is a header file useful.

In the video [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/image_pipeline/Tutorials) I didn't find anything useful either.

I was expecting that I can specify the destination width and height via command line and also get the updated camera info.
Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/332698/example-for-setting-destination-width-and-height-and-getting-updated-camera-info-when-using-image_proc/resize/) by [GXY](https://answers.ros.org/users/36948/gxy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2019-09-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Basically you run the nodelet and remap the input topics. The resize parameters you can change via dynamic reconfigure and/or provide initial values as cmdline parameters.

E.g. to downscale the /stereo/left/image_rect to half the size:

```
rosrun nodelet nodelet standalone image_proc/resize image:=/stereo/left/image_rect camera_info:=/stereo/left/camera_info _scale_width:=0.5 _scale_height:=0.5
```

---

Originally posted by [Felix Ruess](https://answers.ros.org/users/890/felix-ruess/) with karma: 118 on 2019-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vasc](https://answers.ros.org/users/109952/vasc/) on 2022-07-05**:
Hello, I am new to ROS and would like to include this resize in my launch file. Could you help me out with this?
Thanks in advance!

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2022-11-04**:
What it looks like in a launch file:

```
<node name="resized" pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet"
    args="standalone image_proc/resize"
    output="screen">
  <remap from="image" to="/stereo/left/image_rect" />
  <remap from="camera_info" to="/stereo/left/camera_info" />
  <param name="scale_width" value="0.5" />
  <param name="scale_height" value="0.5" />
</node>
```

In a remapping `~image` is the input image (which will appear as resized/image given the node name is resized), while `image` is the output image